# Type of font used in this image

Tags: font-design

[image]

Hello,kindly help me identify this type of font.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's handwritten.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, a bad photocopy of very neat handwriting.

Answer (score 1):

This is handwritten. One important aspects of type is that individual letters are identical when used in the same size and weight. Here the repeated letters S, D, E, A, and D are not identical.

This *style* of type is monoline sans-serif. There is no variation in the stroke weight, and there are no serifs. To get the same impression I would look at sans-serif monospaced typefaces, typically the ones used by programmers in text editing software. DejaVu Sans Mono, Letter Gothic, Source Code Pro.

Comment: While that's possible, the scan is so bad that I don't think you can assume that for certain. Ink spread in printing and bad scanning randomize the image. I think this could be stencil lettering, or using some kind of simplistic, automated machine. Still, it's a good point, I've added a link in my answer to an article on stencils and lettering machines with some examples.

Comment: I don't believe it is handwritten. Despite the apparent differences, I believe this is a poor copy of (maybe poorly-executed) ISO DIN stencilling such as I used at university 35 years ago.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree it could be what I used in architecture school, also 30 years ago. A template and pantograph which held a Rapidograph pen, marketed in the US by K&E LeRoy. I would still consider that hand lettering since no type was used, lead, photo, or computer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image of TGL font by Peter Wiegel]

Block letters? Monoline? Just architectural drawing letters? It's got that "non-designed" look of fonts designed by people who aren't professional type designers, the letters are quite basic shapes and simple, there's no variation in stroke width.

It looks like [a lot of stencil designs](https://www.typotheque.com/articles/from-lettering-guides-to-cnc-plotters-a-brief-history-of-technical-lettering-tools) but with the gaps filled in, so maybe look for stencil fonts with solid styles. Peter Wiegel has done a lot of fonts based on German types of technical lettering, his [TGL family](https://www.1001fonts.com/tgl-font.html) is shown. [He asks for a donation on his website](http://www.peter-wiegel.de) for using them.

K-Type has some fonts that are similar like [Charles Wright](https://www.k-type.com/fonts/charles-wright/) or [Taxicab](https://www.k-type.com/fonts/taxicab/) (rounded) or [Enamela](https://www.k-type.com/fonts/enamela/), or if you want something more designed, more suitable for general-purpose use, try a DIN version like [FF DIN](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/ff-din-font-fontfont) or [DIN Next](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/din-next-font-monotype-imaging).

Most of these have double-story a and a t with a base. If you specifically liked the letterforms in this font maybe look at Futura (there are [many versions of it](https://library.typographica.org/which-futura-should-i-use) available).